# Probability of "sold out"

Tags: probability

A plane has seats in economy class and business class. The probability of "sold out" in at least one of the two classes is $\frac{1}{3}$, while the probability of "sold out" in business class is $\frac{1}{8}$. What is the probability that economy class is "sold out" but business class is not?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like, drawn a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming sold out for econ is independent of sold out for business (and its complement), then denoting sold out for econ is E and sold out for bus as B, we can express the facts as following:

$P(E\bigcup B)$=$P(E)+P(B)-P(E\bigcap B)=P(E)+P(B)-P(E)P(B)=P(E)(1-P(B))+P(B)=1/3$
$P(B)=1/8$ implies (via substitution in the above) that $P(E)(1-P(B))=5/24$

The question can be framed as asking what is $P(E\bigcap B^c)$ which is equal to $P(E)P(B^c)=P(E)(1-P(B))$, which was already solved above.